# How to correctly parse view_state in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nearprotocol

I'm using the `view_state` RPC method and parsing the response via JavaScript. However, it appears most of the returned results are very useable. Is there an example of clearly printable text or another way to parse the data?

```js
const contract = await this.props.near.connection.provider.sendJsonRpc('query', { request_type: 'view_state', finality: 'final', account_id: 'blazenet', prefix_base64: '' });

let contractParsed = contract.values.map((data, i) => {
  return { 'key': atob(data.key).replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, ""), 'val': atob(data.value).replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, "") };
});
```

**Parsed response:**

```js
0: {key: "STATE", val: "blaze.betanet!as+vGj"JV0hxX_/b@zHQXz{Q?!p^/b@zHduiukuv"}
1: {key: "ui ]qU2s7AG5|c7`-?", val: ""}
2: {key: "ui bJ+e,-,[y]CsKUB", val: ""}
3: {key: "ui *EDfC*,#,/", val: ""}
4: {key: "ui ZB\[`VR\/a", val: ""}
5: {key: "ui _|XW==. 0M$l", val: ""}
6: {key: "ui \;>bR?{Ut7/Q", val: ""}
7: {key: "uk", val: " ZB\[`VR\/a"}
8: {key: "uk", val: " \;>bR?{Ut7/Q"}
9: {key: "uk", val: " ]qU2s7AG5|c7`-?"}
10: {key: "uk", val: " *EDfC*,#,/"}
11: {key: "uk", val: " _|XW==. 0M$l"}
12: {key: "uk", val: " bJ+e,-,[y]CsKUB"}
13: {key: "uv", val: "i\s1"}
14: {key: "uv", val: "z-:HYc:"}
15: {key: "uv", val: "Z|"}
16: {key: "uv", val: "Vk/"}
17: {key: "uv", val: "ESQlVA"}
18: {key: "uv", val: "`>(u{|{"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both `key` and `value` are encoded in base64.

Keys and Values might be serialized with `Borsh`, in order to deserialize it you need to know the schema of each key and value. Read more about https://borsh.io

Value under the key `STATE` serializes the main structure of the contract.

Comment: Here is where borsh serilaization is used in [near-api-js](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/master/src/utils/serialize.ts) and here are examples of creating [schemas](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/master/src/transaction.ts).

Comment: here's a small console utility that helps with reading account state.

https://github.com/near-examples/near-account-utils